# How i can get query string from file to query database in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use this code but it's not working

```
var content = fs.readFileSync('/home/diegonode/Desktop/ExpressCart-master/views/partials2/menu8xz.hbs', 'utf8' );


    req.db.products.find( content ).skip(0).limit(3).exec(function (err, results) {
```

please anyone help me (this is a extract of code)

i put the rest of code

```
        req.db.products.find( content          ).skip(0).limit(3).exec(function (err, results) {
                res.render('index', { 
                     title: 'Shop', 
                 results: results, 
                 session: req.session,
                     message: clear_session_value(req.session, "message"),
                 message_type: clear_session_value(req.session, "message_type" , req.body.product_id),
         config: req.config.get('application'),

         helpers: req.handlebars.helpers,
         page_url: req.config.get('application').base_url,

         show_footer: "show_footer"
    });

   console.log(content );
        });
   console.log(content );
        });
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't a useful description of the problem. _How_ is it not working? Is there a stack trace? What's in the file you're reading? What database are you querying, with which mapper? `{ content }` is going to cause a syntax error, but without knowing any of those details it's impossible to tell what you need.

Comment: i put the rest of code in console log appear this {product_title:"XS" }

Comment: when i put content as literally works but when i load data from file not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your mapper's find function expects a conditions object, and when you read `content` directly from the file it's a plain text string that just happens to *look* like an object instead.

You need to do two things: first, "quote" product_title to make the file valid JSON; and second, use `JSON.parse` to turn `content` into an object which `db.products.find` can work with.